# Type SwipeGestureReconizer not found in xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"

Tags: xamarin.forms

I'm trying to set up a side menu to navigate to different pages. But my SwipeReonizer doesn't seem to work

I copied the code from docs(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/gestures/swipe).

XAML :

```
<AbsoluteLayout.GestureRecognizers>
      <SwipeGestureRecognizer Direction="Right" Swiped="SwipeGestureRecognizer_Swiped"/>
</AbsoluteLayout.GestureRecognizers>


<Label x:Name="Username"
    AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="180, 20, 200, 100"
    Text="Sint Gordon" TextColor="White" FontSize="Large"
    FontFamily="Proxima Nova bold">
</Label>
```

C# :

```cs
SwipeGestureRecognizer swipeRecon = new SwipeGestureRecognizer();


private void SwipeGestureRecognizer_Swiped(object sender, SwipedEventArgs e)
   {
     Username.Text = "You swiped right";
   }
```

Comment: you have declared swipegester ecognizer in xaml,so you don't need to `SwipeGestureRecognizer swipeRecon = new SwipeGestureRecognizer();`,and your code works in my side,if you still have issue,you could show your complete xaml and C# codes

Comment: I deleted the variable and added a name to the xaml swipgesturereconizer and get the error The type or namespace name 'SwipeGestureRecognizer' does not exist in the namespace 'Xamarin.Forms' (are you missing an assembly reference?).  I want to post the change but pasting in the comment looks really bad. Is there a different way to post it? And thanks for the help

Comment: you could click `edit` button,below your question,and update your changes